# What should be the values of a, b and c in order to f(t) be a CDF?

Tags: self-study, random-variable, cumulative-distribution-function

> [image]

I have integrated $at^2$ between $0$ and $t$ and found $\frac{at^3}{3}$.

In order to $\frac{at^3}{3}$ be a CDF, $a$ should be equal to zero.

$bt+c$ between $0$ and $2$. and found $t^2 (a + \frac{b}{2}) + ct$.

Now, since $a = 0$, we have $ \frac{t^2b}{2} + ct $.

What should I do next?

Comment: With your edit (you have change the value for $t \gt 2$), $F(t)$ can be a cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (a) for $F(t)$ to be a cumulative distribution function, you need

1. $F(t) \to 0$ as $n \to -\infty$ and
2. $F(t) \to 1$ as $n \to +\infty$ and
3. $F(t)$ to be weakly increasing (and [càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g)).

So for (1) you need $at^2 \to 0$ as $n \to -\infty$ and this results in $a=0$.  For (2) you have $F(t)=1$ for $t \ge 2$ so this is satisfied.  For (3) you need $b \ge 0$ and $c \ge 0$ and $2b+c \le 1$

When it comes to (b), you need $b=0$ as otherwise the random variable will have a density of $b$ between $0$ and $2$ and will not be restricted to discrete values, meaning it can only take the values $0$ and $2$

For (c) you need $F(t)$ to be continuous, including when $t=0$ and $t=2$, so $c=0$ and $2b+c=1$. ***Added by request from comments:*** This leads to $a=0$, $b=1/2$, $c=0$, so the cumulative distribution function $F(t)=0$ for $t<0$, $F(t)=t/2$ for $0≤t<2$ and $F(t)=1$ for $2≤t$, with a density function $f(t)=0$ for $t<0$, $f(t)=1/2$ for $0≤t<2$ and $f(t)=1$ for $2≤t$. So in (c) $F(t)$ is already an integral namely $F(t)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\, dx$

Comment: But, why are we not using Integration here?

Comment: For (a), $a=0$, $b= \frac {1}{2}$ and $c=0$. Am I right?

Comment: @anonymous for (c) rather than (a): $a=0$, $b=\frac12$, $c=0$, so the cumulative distribution function $F(t)=0$ for $t \lt 0$,  $F(t)=t/2$ for $0 \le t \lt 2$ and $F(t)=1$ for $2 \le t$, with a density function $f(t)=0$ for $t \lt 0$,  $f(t)=1/2$ for $0 \le t \lt 2$ and $f(t)=1$ for $2 \le t$.  So in (c) $F(t)$ is already an integral namely $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)\, dx$

Comment: please, include your last comment in your answer.